# mongo repositories base package using java annotation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.jcg.examples.repo")
public class Application {
    @Autowired
    PersonRepo personRepo;
    @Autowired
    AddressRepo addressRepo;

    public void main() throws UnknownHostException {

        try {
            //for mongoTemplate access
            Mongo mongo = new Mongo("www.host", port);
            UserCredentials credentials = new UserCredentials("username", "password");
            MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo, "DbName", credentials);


            System.out.println("connect to database successfully");
            Set<String> collectionsName = mongoTemplate.getCollectionNames();
            System.out.println("Collections Names ###########");
            for (String str : collectionsName) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }
            Person personAchilles = new Person();
            personAchilles.setPersonId(1l);
            personAchilles.setName("Achilles");
            personAchilles.setAge(50);
            personRepo.save(personAchilles);

            Person personHektor = new Person();
            personHektor.setPersonId(2l);
            personHektor.setName("Hektor");
            personHektor.setAge(60);

            Address address = new Address(1, "221b Baker Street", "London NW1", "London", 12345l);
            List<Address> addresses = personHektor.getAddresses();
            addresses.add(address);
            //.......persist data........
            addressRepo.save(address);
            personRepo.save(personHektor);

            //........List data......
            Iterable<Person> personList = personRepo.findAll();
            System.out.println("Person List : ");
            for (Person person : personList) {
                System.out.println(person);
            }
            //........filter data.......                    
            System.out.println("Person with Id 1 is " + personRepo.searchByName("Achilles"));

            context.close();
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //              context.close();

    }
}
```

While executing, MongoDB connection working fine and fetches the record from collection, but persisting using repo class in Mongo is not working.

Please help me to solve this issue using Java annotation. We are not using XML configuration.

Comment: why are you creating separate mongo client instead of using spring one ? also are you using spring boot ?

Comment: 2 questions.. 1. Why dont you use? @Autowired if you using annotations. . 2. Where is the code to persist data. Please give detailed implementations of these addressRepo.save(address)             personRepo.save(personHektor);

Comment: public interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>
{
  @Query("{'name' : ?0}")
  public Iterable<Person> searchByName(String personName);

}

Comment: Here Autowired object(personRepo and addressRepo) is null...could you please help me how to inject the repo class bean property

Comment: @marknorkin: we want to encrypt and decrypt  userName/password thats why using mongo client